# How to get the time difference of first occurrence of a record with another record

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a monitoring system that posts data to our postgres database in this format:

Our goal is to calculate the time between `wa-event-triggered` events and `wa-event-recovered` events, if i have data that looks like this, my query below works just fine.

```
ts                           |   text
-----------------------------+------------------+
2021-04-15T18:35:08.000000Z  | wa-event-triggered
2021-04-15T18:45:08.000000Z  | wa-event-recovered
2021-04-15T18:50:08.000000Z  | wa-event-triggered
2021-04-15T18:55:08.000000Z  | wa-event-recovered
```

```
select *
from (
select text, ts,
       CAST(ts as timestamp) - lag(CAST(ts as timestamp)) over (order by CAST(ts as timestamp)) as increase
from messages
where text ~ 'wa-event-'
) as alerts
where alerts.text ~ 'recovered'
;
```

This gives me this table which is great!

```
ts                           |   text             |   Increase
-----------------------------+--------------------+-----------------+ 
2021-04-15T18:45:08.000000Z  | wa-event-recovered | 00:10:00
2021-04-15T18:55:08.000000Z  | wa-event-recovered | 00:05:00
```

However the data is not always sequential in that our alerting system can post multiple `wa-event-triggered` events before we finally have a `wa-event-recovered` event, so how would i get the time difference between the first `wa-event-triggered` found and the first `wa-event-recovered` found and ignore all the `wa-event-triggered` events in between given that there will be hundreds of these triggered/recovered pairs.

```
ts                           |   text
-----------------------------+------------------+
2021-04-15T18:35:08.000000Z  | wa-event-triggered     <- start timer
2021-04-15T18:45:08.000000Z  | wa-event-triggered
2021-04-15T18:55:08.000000Z  | wa-event-triggered
2021-04-15T18:50:08.000000Z  | wa-event-recovered     <- end timer
2021-04-15T19:00:00.000000Z  | wa-event-triggered     <- start timer
2021-04-15T19:05:08.000000Z  | wa-event-triggered
2021-04-15T19:10:08.000000Z  | wa-event-triggered
2021-04-15T19:15:08.000000Z  | wa-event-recovered     <- end timer
2021-04-15T20:05:08.000000Z  | wa-event-triggered     <- start timer
2021-04-15T20:10:08.000000Z  | wa-event-triggered
2021-04-15T20:15:08.000000Z  | wa-event-recovered     <- end timer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just include the changed records and use your method:

```
select *
from (select text, ts,
             ts::timestamp - lag(ts::timestamp) over (order by ts::timestamp) as increase
      from (select m.*,
                   lag(text) over (order by ts::timestamp) as prev_text
            from messages m
            where text ~ 'wa-event-' or alerts.text ~ 'recovered'
           ) m
      where text ~ 'wa-event-' and
            prev_text is distinct from text
     ) alerts
where alerts.text ~ 'recovered';
```

Comment: Woah you are a ninja man!! One small edit i got a syntax error, just needed to remove the `alerts.text` and make it just `text`